# How to use the writeCloud() OpenCV function to contruct point cloud given 3D point coordinates?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, 3d

I'm beginner in OpenCV and currently I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (64-bit) and OpenCV 3.2 (C++) to construct a two view geometry and try to display those matched 3D points in MeshLab. I use the `triangulatePoints()` to get the Points4D, which is a 4*N matrix that contains the coordinates of the matched points from two images. This the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/d19/group__viz.html#gac2afffcdc8346762a0979664e9e2b249) of `writeCloud()`.

```
triangulatePoints(CameraMatrix_1, CameraMatrix_2, matchpoints_1, matchpoints_2, Points4D);
writeCloud("twoview.ply", cloud, noArray(), noArray(), false);
```

My question is, what should be the `cloud` input of `writeCloud()` so that I could save those 3D points into a .ply file and display them? Assume that I do not assign color to the point cloud first.

Also, I have tried to use the MATLAB to generate a `pointcloud.ply` file and analyse it with the `readCloud()`, then I find out the following code successfully read a point cloud and save it into another one. But strangely, the `cv::Mat twoviewcloud` here is a 1*N matrix, how could you construct a point cloud form one dimensional array? I am totally confused.

```
Mat twoviewcloud = readCloud("pointcloud.ply");
writeCloud("trial.ply", twoviewcloud, noArray(), noArray(), false);
```

I would sincerely thank you if someone could give me some hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I am still confused to use the original OpenCV function `writeCloud()`, however, I could just implement my own function to write the `.ply` file. Here is the code, it is quite simple actually and you could read the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLY_(file_format)) page for the detailed `.ply` format.

```
struct dataType { Point3d point; int red; int green; int blue; };
typedef dataType SpacePoint;
vector<SpacePoint> pointCloud;

ofstream outfile("pointcloud.ply");
outfile << "ply\n" << "format ascii 1.0\n" << "comment VTK generated PLY File\n";
outfile << "obj_info vtkPolyData points and polygons : vtk4.0\n" << "element vertex " << pointCloud.size() << "\n";
outfile << "property float x\n" << "property float y\n" << "property float z\n" << "element face 0\n";
outfile << "property list uchar int vertex_indices\n" << "end_header\n";
for (int i = 0; i < pointCloud.size(); i++)
{
    Point3d point = pointCloud.at(i).point;
    outfile << point.x << " ";
    outfile << point.y << " ";
    outfile << point.z << " ";
    outfile << "\n";
}
outfile.close();
```